# why is this not working, undefined blank for string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following:

```
  input = gets.chomp
  basket = input.strip.split(',')
  basket.delete_if(&:blank?)
```

which should allow you to do: `cat, dog,,`

from there we can split that up, strip it clean and split it on `,` and then check for empty elements and remove them.

but this code gives me an error: `delete_if: undefined method 'blank?' for "cat":String (NoMethodError)` which does not make any sense to me. I thought that the whole purpose of blank? or empty? was to say remove this element if this is true.

Answer (score 4):

`ActiveSupport` that comes with Rails adds the `blank?` method to `String` and many other classes. Since this method is not part of Ruby core, you need to have Rails or the ActiveSupport gem installed. If that gem is installed than you can require ActiveSupport's core extensions like this:

```
> 'foo'.blank?
# => NoMethodError: undefined method `blank?' for "foo":String

> require 'active_support/core_ext'
# => true

> 'foo'.blank?
# => false
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

import "active_support" first

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 3):

`blank?` is a method augmented to the `String` class from rails. It's not part of the ruby `String` class by default.